# Is it possible to create a hash with attributes?

Tags: ruby, hash, attributes

I want to be able to take the id from another collection, and use that as the key for a hash.  Then I would like to be able to apply various attributes to each.  It would be something like:

```
@books = Hash.new

@books[key].title = "A Title"
@books[key].condition = "Poor"
@books[key].rating = "Excellent"
```

or something to that effect.  Is this even possible with some tweaks?

Thanks for your time!

Edit: I should have added that it is undesirable to create a Class in this case, although I may end up having to do that.

Comment: What's the problem with creating a class? Do you don't know which keys you will get? then you could solve the problem with method_missing. (example will follow in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738911/is-it-possible-to-create-a-hash-with-attributes/6739133#6739133))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multidimensional Hash?

```
@books = Book.all
@books_hash = {}
@books.each do |book|
  @books_hash[book.id] = {}
  @books_hash[book.id][:title] = book.title
  @books_hash[book.id][:rating] = book.rating
end
```

Comment: `@books_hash[book.id][:title]` is going to give you a `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]'` unless you init the second tier hash first, `@books_hash[book.id] = {}`.

Comment: Okay thank you.  I didn't consider/know about multidimensional hashes in Ruby.  I'm working on getting that to work now, and I think I have it.  And thanks diedthreetimes, I was in fact getting a NoMethodError: undefined method.  I'm trying to figure out now how to iterate through the hashmap, printing out the value of each second tier hash. In haml.

Comment: @mu: Actually, change `Hash.new { { } }` to `Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = { } }`, otherwise you changes won't get recorded.

Comment: @mu: You might want to double check. `h=Hash.new { { } }; h[:foo][:bar]=24; h[:foo] # => {}`

Answer (score 3):

If you want exactly that syntax you can create a hash of `OpenStruct`s:

```
require 'ostruct'
@books = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = OpenStruct.new }
key = 1
@books[key].title = "A Title"
@books[key].condition = "Poor"
@books[key].rating = "Excellent"
@books #=> {1=>#<OpenStruct title="A Title", condition="Poor", rating="Excellent">}
```

Comment: +1 for OpenStruct. I find all the ` #=> ...` unhelpful except the last one... I didn't edit them out, but I removed the leading `>> `.

Comment: @Marc-André: Thanks, it's a direct copy from my IRB where `irb_rocket` puts the return value on every line. It was late and I didn't feel like editing the post.

Comment: Didn't know about `irb_rocket`, cute idea :-)

Answer (score 1):

You probably never want to do this, but just to answer the question.

> > Is this even possible with some tweaks?

Yes, we can create our own class to do this pretty easily.

```
class MyAnonObject
  attr_accessor attributes

  def attributes
    @attributes ||= {}
  end

  def method_missing method, *args, &block
    if method =~ /^(\w+)=$/
      @attributes[$1] = args[0]
    else
      @attributes[$1]
    end     
  end
end
```

And then we can modify your example to use this new class.

```
@books = Hash.new { MyAnonObject.new }

@books[key].title = "A Title"
@books[key].condition = "Poor"
@books[key].rating = "Excellent"
```

That being said, I wouldn't recommend this solution. It can be very confusing to read. However, it is possible =) And really, this is just a multi-dimensional hash with strange semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object of type Book.

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :tilte, :rating, :condition
end
```

And then modify your example to use the new Book class.

```
@books = Hash.new

@books[key] = Book.new
@books[key].title = "A Title"
@books[key].condition = "Poor"
@books[key].rating = "Excellent"
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I never specified.  I won't say that I necessarily CAN'T make a class in this case, but it is very undesirable in this isolated case.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to diedthreetimes anser, but the Book.new is done by the Hash:

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title
  attr_accessor :condition
  attr_accessor :rating
  def initialize()
    @undefined_values = {}
  end
  def method_missing ( m, *args )
    @undefined_values[m] = args
  end
  def inspect()
    "Book #{@title} (#{@condition}, #{@rating}, #{@undefined_values.inspect})"
  end
end  
@books = Hash.new{ |hash,k| hash[k] =  Book.new 
}

key = :xx
@books[key].title = "A Title"
@books[key].condition = "Poor"
@books[key].rating = "Excellent"
@books[key].isbn = "123456"

p @books[key] #-> Book A Title (Poor, Excellent, {:isbn==>["123456"]})
```

edit: Added code to handle undefined values.
    p @books[key]